# Добавление записи в Many to Many связь MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

Есть many to many связь между 2-мя таблицами с помощью третьей таблицы:

Таблица 1 Facts:

```
    create table Facts
(
  text    text not null,
  fact_id int auto_increment
    primary key,
  constraint fact_id_UNIQUE
  unique (fact_id)
);
```

Таблица 2 Tags:

```
    create table Tags
(
  tag_id      int auto_increment
    primary key,
  name        varchar(32) not null,
  description text        not null,
  constraint tag_id_UNIQUE
  unique (tag_id),
  constraint name_UNIQUE
  unique (name)
);
```

И 3-я связующая таблица FactsTags:

```
create table FactsTags
(
  id      int(32) auto_increment
    primary key,
  fact_id int not null,
  tag_id  int not null,
  constraint id_UNIQUE
  unique (id),
  constraint fk_FactTags
  foreign key (fact_id) references Facts (fact_id)
    on delete cascade,
  constraint fk_TagFacts
  foreign key (tag_id) references Tags (tag_id)
    on delete cascade
);
```

При добавление какого либа факта, если теги уже существуют мне придётся делать 2 запроса? 1 чтобы создать запись факта, а второй чтобы добавить записи в связующую таблицу? Или как-то возможно 1 запросом добавлять факт и сразу записи с тегами на которые он ссылается.

Помогите пожалуйста, искал в интернете, пока что не нашёл.

Comment: Запроса на добавление `INSERT INTO` в несколько таблиц не существует. См. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html Так что да, два запроса. Впрочем, если библиотека доступа позволяет мультизапросы, можно послать их одним пакетом, одной командой.

Comment: @Akina печально, но спасибо

Comment: Подумайте в направлении вынесения логики на сервер и создания хранимой процедуры. Передаёте ей все данные в одном запросе, а она выполняет все необходимые операции записи во все таблицы с необходимыми согласованиями значений связанных полей.

Comment: @Akina у меня есть такие java классы DAO, я в них это и делаю, просто думал, что возможно это делать в 1 запросе.

Comment: Так и получится один запрос `CALL mysub(параметры)`, который раскидает данные из параметров по таблицам. PS. И при чём тут вообще Java?

Comment: @Akina, я на ней пишу